# How to calculate ETA time with Google Maps API - Swift

Tags: swift

I am drawing a route with Google map. I calculate the km distance on the route I drew. I also want to calculate how long it will go. How can I calculate how many minutes the route will take? I calculated the speed in the code below and when I tried to calculate the time using the speed I could not get any output. How can I calculate the duration?

```
func drowRoute(from source: CLLocationCoordinate2D, to destination: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
          self.mapView.clear()

          let origin = "\(source.latitude),\(source.longitude)"
          let destinationn = "\(destination.latitude),\(destination.longitude)"

          guard let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(origin)&destination=\(destinationn)&mode=driving&key=..") else {
              let error = NSError(domain: "LocalDomain", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Failed to create object URL"])
              print("Error: \(error)")
              return
          }
          let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
          let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
          let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
              (data, response, error) in
              if error != nil {
                  print(error!.localizedDescription)
              }
              else {
                  do {
                      if let json : [String:Any] = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]{

                          guard let routes = json["routes"] as? NSArray else {
                              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                              }
                              return
                          }
                          if (routes.count > 0) {
                              let overview_polyline = routes[0] as? NSDictionary
                              let dictPolyline = overview_polyline?["overview_polyline"] as? NSDictionary
                              let points = dictPolyline?.object(forKey: "points") as? String

                              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                  //
                                  let legs = overview_polyline?["legs"] as! Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>

                    let distance = legs[0]["distance"] as? NSDictionary
                    let distanceValue = distance?["value"] as? Int ?? 0
                    let distanceDouleValue = distance?["value"] as? Double ?? 0.0
                    let duration = legs[0]["duration"] as? NSDictionary
                    let totalDurationInSeconds = duration?["value"] as? Int ?? 0
                    let durationDouleValue = duration?["value"] as? Double ?? 0.0

                                    if(distanceValue != 0) {
                                self.speed = distanceDouleValue / durationDouleValue
                                        print("speed", self.speed)
                                                                                }

                                  let miles = Double(distanceValue) / 1609.344
                                  print("\(miles)")
                                  let km = Double(distanceValue) * 0.001609
                                  self.kmLabel.text = ("\(Int(km))" + " " + "KM")



                                  if distanceValue > Int(32186.9){

                                  }else{
                                      self.showPath(polyStr: points!)

                                      let startLocationDictionary = legs[0]["start_location"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                                      let originCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(startLocationDictionary["lat"] as! Double, startLocationDictionary["lng"] as! Double)

                                      let endLocationDictionary = legs[legs.count - 1]["end_location"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                                      let destinationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(endLocationDictionary["lat"] as! Double, endLocationDictionary["lng"] as! Double)

                                      let marker1 = GMSMarker()
                                      marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:destinationCoordinate.latitude, longitude: destinationCoordinate.longitude)
                                      marker1.icon = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
                                      marker1.map = self.mapView

                                      let marker2 = GMSMarker()
                                      marker2.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:originCoordinate.latitude, longitude: originCoordinate.longitude)
                                      marker2.icon = UIImage(named: "location")
                                      marker2.map = self.mapView

                                  }

                              }
                          }
                          else {
                              print(json)
                              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                               //   SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
                  catch {
                      print("error in JSONSerialization")
                      DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        //  SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                      }
                  }
              }
          })
          task.resume()
      }

      func showPath(polyStr :String){
        //  SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
          let path = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: polyStr)
          let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
          polyline.strokeWidth = 5.0
          polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.red
          polyline.map = mapView
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
              let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(path: path!)
              let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, with: UIEdgeInsets(top: 170, left: 30, bottom: 30, right: 30))
              self.mapView.moveCamera(update)

          }
      }
```

Comment: I think the basic formula is `time = distance/speed`. But, are you updating speed and distance? Or do you need at the beginning to show them the time?

Comment: I want to update the speed and duration continuously. When I just calculated it over that formula, 15 km road time = 918.0 came out. 918 minutes isn't it? What is the problem? @Rob